# How can I create a custom page with #react-admin without the menu sidebar like login page?

Tags: reactjs, menu, react-admin, custom-pages

I am using react-admin previously admin-on-rest. I want to create a custom page that doesn't show the Menu sidebar, like Login page. I will use this page reset user's password. How can I do that?

Comment: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#applayout

Comment: I don't want to change all my Layout . I just want to create a page that is not in the react-admin layout

Comment: You can achieve this using custom menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I already have a custom Menu. I just want to have a page like login page to reset  a user password.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not obvious in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes) but the `Route` actually accepts a `noLayout` prop:

```
<Admin
    customRoutes={[
        <Route
            path="/custom"
            component={CustomRouteNoLayout}
            noLayout
        />,
        <Route
            path="/custom2"
            component={CustomRouteWithLayout}
        />,
    ]}
>
```

Comment: v4 now has the following in their documentation: ```Tip: In previous versions of react-admin, you had to write <Route noLayout> instead of <RouteWithoutLayout>. The former still works in Js projects but TypeScript won’t compile it.```
So you need to change that unless you are using .js

Answer (score 3):

Add a [custom route](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes) with the component you want to render. When route is successful the specified component will be presented. No `Menu` will be shown just whatever you have in the component you send as prop to `Route`.

The way you put the question it seemed like you were trying to have a custom page that hadn't a `MenuItemLink` in `Menu`. Had to reread the question to understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add on to Gildas Garcia's answer. After you added the customed routes as shown in the documentation, you need to add a hash `#` in front of the route url to be able to view the content. 
For example, if you are displaying the view at `localhost:3000/`, and one of your routes is

```
<Route exact path="/foo" component={Foo} />,
```

then you should go to `localhost:3000/#/foo` to view the content.

Comment: If anyone knows how to get rid of the hash `#` in the url please let me know!

Comment: It depends on the router history you're using. You can pass your own to react-admin

Answer (score 0):

As per current [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomRoutes.html#nolayout) (v4.12.1) you can use the `noLayout` property available in the `CustomRoutes` component:

```js
const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <CustomRoutes noLayout>
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        </CustomRoutes>
        <CustomRoutes>
            <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </CustomRoutes>
    </Admin>
);
```